# Opening .RAW with data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, raw

I am working with some public data found [here](https://data.nber.org/exempt-orgs/1987/). As you can see, they both include a `.raw` file and a file that ends in `.87`. I believe these files my include some data that I want to check and want to get to read in R as a `data.frame`. For this, I have tried adapting the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361059/import-raw-image-in-r) and my code is:

```
library(hexView)
l <- readRaw("...//f990-1987.raw")
df<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=length(l), byrow=TRUE))
head(df)
```

But I obtain a non-nonsensical output. I am trying to figure out how this `.raw` files may be structured, but perhaps some of you have some documentation or tips?

I have also managed to read the `.87` file using my web browser but I am not sure of how to open it on R.

**Update after comment from @Gregor Thomas**

I actually used `readLines()` and manage to read the data, it looks like this:

```
> head(l)
[1] "0016NORTH MEMORIAL MEDICAL CENTER      410729979900000000000003591283MN5542203220000122410729979083+000000048470+000000040000+000000000000+000000088470+000064439626+000000000000+000000592451+000000000000+000000689818+000000679830+000000009988+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000001547177+000066677712+000062281763+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000062281763+000004395949+000018515214+000000000000+000022911163+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000034740795+000034740795+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000005456091+000005456091+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000009735699+000009735699+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000001578619+000001578619+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000003659097+000003659097+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000007111462+000007111462+000000000000+000000000000+000062281763+000062281763+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000064439626+000002205685+000000558069+000000000000+000013978806+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000716725+000000645024+000000172792+000000479997+000001497077+000000000000+000000000000+000030231955+000021194913+000039173747+000068278636+000012461784+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000032620623+000000285066+000020448482+000045367473+000000247302+000000000000+000000000000+000022663861+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000022911163+000039173747+000068278636+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000301147350011170011380000102000000000000000000"
[2] "0017BILLY GRAHAM EVANGELISTIC ASSOC    410692230900000000000003491283MN5540303220000321410692230123+000046885293+000000000000+000000000000+000046885293+000000266541+000000000000+000000981254+000000111117+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000128227+000000125972+000000130247-000000004275+000000083603+000000049441+000000034162+000000029887+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000053265+000048455584+000037851465+000002343183+000003224973+000000000000+000043419621+000005035963+000014187098+000000000000+000019223061+000006279538+000000000000+000000000000+000000505963+000000381617+000000124346+000000000000+000006136673+000004514858+000000977352+000000644463+000000200226+000000148692+000000032256+000000019278+000000525456+000000387019+000000087028+000000051409+000000392772+000000295379+000000053759+000000043634+000000000000+000000033680+000000000000+000000033680+000000000000+000000051401+000000007710+000000043691+000000000000+000000388077+000000286505+000000054527+000000047045+000000378664+000000308936+000000057077+000000012651+000002878737+000001708438+000000043523+000001126776+000000267996+000000077076+000000156919+000000034001+000000310941+000000164893+000000077805+000000068243+000005320044+000004547975+000000057948+000000714121+000001652878+000001504291+000000073575+000000075012+000000626882+000000620459+000000003653+000000002770+000000000574+000000000212+000000000291+000000000071+000000583988+000000238829+000000229505+000000115654+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000016885131+000016379038+000000236248+000000269845+000043419621+000037851465+000002343183+000003224973+000000000000+000000000000+000000266541+000000053265+000000828829+000013378120+000001241197+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000001112173+000000226217+000000125280+000000457831+000000000000+000000000000+000000917794+000008929886+000005174263+000000000000+000024988453+000032165373+000001740590+000000675934+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000010525788+000010801355+000012942312+000019223061+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000019223061+000024988453+000032165373+000000000000+000042113131+000145546846+000000000000+000000000000+000000313977+000000876109+000001937596+000005245837+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000000000000+000044364704+000151668792+000044050727+000150792683+000000443647+000000000000+000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000301148340033300037770000113000000000000000000"
```

Comment: Looking at how the `.raw` files displays in the browser, my best guess is it's a fixed width file. I'd suggest trying `read.fwf()` not `readRaw`. You may have to look at the file and do some counting to figure out what the widths are for each field.

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor, it was a bit hard to infer width, I did use 'readLines' and updated my output above.

Comment: Yes, fixed width files are painful without a data dictionary.