# How to convert data in a character class object to dataframe in R

Tags: r, readlines

I basically have the same (unanswered) question as [this fellow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113598/opening-raw-with-data-in-r) -- I want to import the .raw data file [at this link](https://adfdell.pstc.brown.edu/arisreds_data/public82/redwt.raw) and convert the data within into a matrix/dataframe.

I downloaded redwt.raw to a folder, set my working directory to that folder, and followed the advice at the link above to import it via this code:

```
test <- readLines("redwt.raw", n = -1)
```

That works to create a character class object called test, where I can see my data. But I am not sure how to convert the data held within that object into a dataframe. The output should be a 2-column matrix; in it's current form, each odd column is an ID, and each even column is a corresponding sampling weight for the ID that came before it. So I'd like to loop through the numbers in the .raw file to create a ?x2 matrix dataframe.

Comment: Please post a few lines of your raw file so that we can see the format without downloading it. 3-5 lines should be plenty. If it's in a standard format, there is probably a function to read it into a data frame directly. If it's in a strange format, then you may need to start with `readLines` and then do some processing. `read.table()` is often a good place to start in base R.

Comment: Based on Gregor's comment in the linked question, you might try `read.fwf('https://adfdell.pstc.brown.edu/arisreds_data/public82/redwt.raw', widths = rep(8, 10))` This reads in the columns with made-up header names V1 through V10, based on the observation that the data is 10 columns of 8 characters each.

Comment: Gregor -- Adding now. But if you click on the (second) link above you can see the .raw file yourself, it's openly accessible. Also, as I stated, I am starting with readLines,  it's just that I don't know what to do with the resulting object. You can create the resulting object yourself by running the code I gave on the linked data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That* data looks really simple to import, many assumptions. Notable is that they are alternating pairs (and not *rows of observations*).

If the data looks like this:

```
       1     437       2     437       3     437       4     437       5     437
       7     437       8     437       9     437      10     437      11     437
      12     437      13     437      14     437      15     437      16     437
      17     437      18     437      19     437      20     437      21     707
```

Then we can do this:

```r
mydat <- readLines("https://adfdell.pstc.brown.edu/arisreds_data/public82/redwt.raw") |>
  # or `readLines("redwt.raw")` if already downloaded, no need to download repeatedly
  trimws() |>
  strsplit(" +") |>
  unlist() |>
  matrix(ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |>
  data.frame()
head(mydat)
#   X1  X2
# 1  1 437
# 2  2 437
# 3  3 437
# 4  4 437
# 5  5 437
# 6  7 437
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! ... For the first 17 numbers only. Using your code exactly, I only get the first 7 observations of the 2 variables. Are you getting all observations? What's going on that it stalling for me at 7?

Comment: I get 4,981 rows (2 columns) when I run this code. If you're not getting the same number, then I would not assume "perfectly" is the best word for it :-)

Comment: No, perfectly is not the right descriptor, you are right. Can you help me trouble-shoot? The resulting dataframe I get is "6 obs. of 2 variables" with $X1 as "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" and $X2 as "437" "437" "437" "437" "437" "437". And this is the same whether I use the downloaded data or go straight from the website.

Comment: Okay, the `head()` was purely for demonstration in the answer. Remove that, and store it into a variable, such as `mydat <- readLines(...) |> ... |> data.frame()`

Comment: Ohh... I'm an idiot, I had stored the output in a variable but w/out dropping the |> head() component, I just wasn't looking that closely line by line because I don't know all those commands. Thank you!!